# Observable in Java not working properly?

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

Ok, so I've used observers for projects before, and I'm following the exact same methodology for this one, but for some reason my update method in my observer does not get called at all.

In my Android Application Activity:

```
public void newGame(View view)
{
    poleLeft.clear();
}
```

In my Pole class:

```
public void clear()
{
    stack.clear();
    size = 0;
    head = 0;

    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

In my View class:

```
private class PoleObserver implements Observer
{
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data)
    {
        postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

and:

```
    leftPole.addObserver(new PoleObserver());
```

Essentially all I want to do is have a certain number of items on the Pole (poleLeft), clear it, and have the application view redraw to reflect these changes. However, when I click the button the Pole is cleared, but the view does not changed, and putting a System.out.println in the update method never gets output so it's never being run. Why would this be??

Comment: Maybe post your addObserver and notifyObservers implementations too?

Comment: I am using the built in Java implementations for that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

Comment: Wait, are you sure it's not running? System.out.println isn't often useful in Android. Try either setting a breakpoint there or using `Log.d("Pole", "Observer updated");` and looking in LogCat.

Comment: I am positive it is not running. It calls setChanged(), notifyObservers(), goes to the observer class (PoleObserver) and then skips over update.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing something out of order? This example works fine for me.

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class Pole extends Observable {

    public void clear()
    {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public static class PoleObserver implements Observer
    {
        public void update(Observable observable, Object data)
        {
            System.out.println("Updated");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pole p = new Pole();
        p.addObserver(new Pole.PoleObserver());
        p.clear();

    }

}
```

Comment: But what on earth would I be calling out of order? I've used this exact technique before and it should work perfectly... I know there's not much you can do to help, but it's just extremely frustrating.

Comment: Try putting a break point in your code and stepping through it line by line or putting a break point on the `postInvalidate` and see if it gets hit.

Comment: I have tried using a break point, and it is never hit. That is my problem, I have absolutely no idea why it is never hit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be posting the "real" code as in the game constructor you use `poleLeft` and in the view class `leftPole`.  Without a small, runnable example there are few ways we can help.

(Or maybe this discrepancy is the source of the problem!)

Some suggestions:

- Use `@override` to ensure the `update` method really is implementing the `interface` as you think it is.  Perhaps you're importing another `Observer` that works differently from the one you think you're getting.
- Use `Log` calls to be sure you're really installing the observer on the same observable you think you are.  You can do this by printing objects' `identityHashCode` to the log.